# loop through folders in a directory without listing

Tags: unix, loops, directory

i am inside a directory called TestJ. Inside this directory i have many folders like MSC1,MSC2 ... MSC19, HLR1,HLR2 .. ,SGSN1,SGSN2 .. .Now inside each of these directories is a script ALARMS.sh. What i want to do is loop through all these folders and execute ALARMS.sh in each folder . what my present code does is use this

```
ls -d SGSN* > temp.txt
while read sgsn_line;do
    echo $sgsn_line
    cd $sgsn_line
    ALARMS.sh
    cd ..
done < temp.txt

ls -d HLR* > temp.txt
while read hlr_line;do
    echo $hlr_line
    cd $hlr_line
    ALARMS.sh
    cd ..
done < temp.txt

ls -d MSC* > temp.txt
while read msc_line;do
    echo $msc_line
    cd $msc_line
    ALARMS.sh
    cd ..
done < temp.txt
rm temp.txt
```

But i want to do the same job without listing the folders in any file. like for example we can loop through files in a given folder using `for file in *.txt`. I would like to be able to do the same for folders(only folders).

Comment: How about `for f in MSC*/ SGSN*/ HLR*/ ; do echo "$f"; done` ?

Comment: yeah this works i know. but the thing is i cant keep any files whose names end with MSC* else even those will be included Banthar.

Comment: kk my bad your script works. im assuming the slash is to denote folders only. put it as an answer, will accept it. neat trick. @Banthar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use like below...**

```
for sgsn_line in `ls -ltr SGSN* | grep ^d | awk '{print $NF}'`;do
    echo $sgsn_line
    cd $sgsn_line
    ALARMS.sh
    cd ..
done

....
```

Comment: this will also work. Banthar isn't replying his is the smarter n shorter way, but your answer works fine. thanks.

Comment: It is very fragile to do `cd ..`.  Much better to only cd in a subshell and let that subshell exit, leaving the main script in the directory it started in.  `for ...; do (cd $sgsn_line && ./ALARMS.sh); done`

Answer (score 0):

If your version of `find` supports the `-execdir` option, the easiest thing to do is:

```
find . -name ALARMS.sh -type f -execdir {} \;
```